# Django Production - collectstatic each time?

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, production-environment, django-staticfiles

I'm running a Django production server with WSGI & Apache.
I'm wondering if I have to run a `collectstatic` each time I modify a little static file.
Isn't there a way to let WSGI or whichever program automate this process ?

Comment: I've added the the colleccstatic command to my fabric deployment script (push local changes, pull changes from remote, collectstatic, restart server).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.0/index.html) to automate deployment and as one of the steps i just run collectstatic.

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know Fabric. I'm going to look further into it.

Comment: I also found this [quite good tutorial](http://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/django-python-fabric-deployment-script-and-example/) about Fabric with Django

Comment: [This](http://www.clemesha.org/blog/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip) is the article where i discovered fabric, also introduced me to virtualenv and pip

Comment: How do you get fabric to automatically answer yes when it asks if you are sure you want to run this command?

Comment: @Dustin: You can give the `--noinput` argument to `collectstatic`.